# 301 Old content to New Content but now different language (negative SEO effect?)

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, ranking, google-ranking

I have a question. I have a Dutch website and used to receive backlinks from good and high-quality websites. Now, I want to 301 redirect the Dutch page to an English page. Will this affect my website's SEO, even though the content is essentially the same but now in English? The backlinks I have received are in Dutch, but I want to switch to English. Will this change impact my website? I read somewhere that I should use something like: `<html lang="en">` to minimize the impact. Can someone provide guidance on this matter?